# AndroidStudio google Maps(lanzar mapa por mediante Boton)

Tags: android-studio

Buenas a todos, soy nuevo en Android y estoy probando la  Api de google, para practicar se me ocurrió crear un menú principal con un botón, que al presionar este me lanzé un mapa con coordenadas específicas.

Realice pruebas de la api desde el `main activity` y funciona correctamete.

Actualmente me carga el `main layout` pero al darle clic al botón no lanza el mapa.
Lo que pretende es pasarle los parámetros a otra `class` y que esta clase gestione los parámetros y presente el mapa.
Aca el código:

MainActivity:

```
package company.project.phk.whereisit;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    public GoogleMap mGoogle;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView TV1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.PraderaColor);
        TV1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                mapClass miMapa= new mapClass();
                miMapa.setDatos(14.8499202,-91.5375707,"Mi Ubicacion");

            }
        });

    }


}
```

MainActivity xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    >

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Miubicacioin"
    android:textAlignment="center"

    />
    </LinearLayout>
```

mapClass: en esta clase pretendo que reciba los parametros y lanze el mapa.

```
package company.project.phk.whereisit;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;


public class mapClass  extends FragmentActivity implements  OnMapReadyCallback {

    public GoogleMap mGoogle;
    public Double Coordenada1;
    public Double Coordenada2;
    public String Messaje;
    public LatLng miUbicacion;



    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mapalayout);

     MapFragment mapF = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapa);
        mapF.getMapAsync(mapClass.this);

   }

    public void setDatos( Double c1, Double c2, String m )
    {
        Coordenada1=c1;
        Coordenada2=c2;
        Messaje=m;
    }

    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

      //  mGoogle = googleMap;
        miUbicacion = new LatLng(Coordenada1, Coordenada2);
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(miUbicacion).title(Messaje));
       googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(miUbicacion, 16));


    }

}
```

mapLayout xml

```
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mapa"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

Ante todo gracias,por tomarse el tiempo y verificar mi pregunta.

¿Cómo hacer para que desde el botón se ejecute correctamente el mapa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esa no es la forma de pasar parámetros entre actividades/fragmentos
Tip: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739909/send-data-from-activity-to-fragment-in-android

Te aconsejo que leas algo de teoría sobre cómo funcionan las actividades y los fragmentos, la comunicación entre ellos y luego vuelvas a intentar este ejemplo que estás haciendo.

Comment: Gracias, me estaba equivocando, estaba tomando el activity como una clase normal, para pasar parámetros esto lo hice a través de Intents.